# what is missing in my array.map function?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table with v-for that works. (added to snippet)
But I want to use `Array.map` to map one array to another. I need my first column networkTeam.source to show a color instead of a number. I tried using .map in method but it isn't working and I'm not getting any errors in the console.

Can you help me figure out what is wrong in my function? thanks in advance

```js
data(){
  networkTeams: {},
  sources: {
       1: 'green',
       2: 'blue',
       3: 'pink',
       4: 'yellow',
       5: 'orange',
       6: 'blue'
       },

methods: {
        fixedNetworkTeams(teamId)
        {     
            return this.networkTeams(teamId).data.map(u => 
            {
                return { ...u, source: this.sources[u.source]};
            });
        },
```

```html
<-- table no longer works -->

<tr v-for="networkTeam in fixedNetworkTeams"
    :key="team.id + networkTeam.id"
    :class="{ odd2: networkTeam.id % 2 !== 0 }"
>                    
  <td>
       <span> {{ networkTeam.source }} </span>
  </td>

  <td class="text-center data-column">
      <span> {{ networkTeam.accountId }} </span>
  </td>
  <td class="text-nowrap text-left breakAll">
      <span> {{ networkTeam.name }}</span>
  </td>
</tr>


<-- table before .map that works -->
<tr v-for="(networkTeam) in networkTeams[team.id].data"
    :key="team.id + networkTeam.id"
    :class="{ odd2: networkTeam.id % 2 !== 0 }"
>                    
  <td>
       <span> {{ networkTeam.source }} </span>
  </td>

  <td class="text-center data-column">
      <span> {{ networkTeam.accountId }} </span>
  </td>
  <td class="text-nowrap text-left breakAll">
      <span> {{ networkTeam.name }}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `this.networkTeams(teamId)` should be `this.networkTeams[teamId]`

Comment: With this approach you will get an "Cannot read .. of undefined"

Comment: You're trying to read the `data` property of `networkTeams`, but it doesn't exist because `networkTeams` is an empty object. You could iterate sources instead as that's where your colours are stored

Answer (score 0):

Accessing team from object should be done using `[]`:

```js
fixedNetworkTeams(teamId)
{     
    return this.networkTeams[teamId].data.map(u => 
    {
        return { ...u, source: this.sources[u.source]};
    });
}
```

You should provide your `team.id` when iterating over collection:

```html
<tr v-for="networkTeam in fixedNetworkTeams(team.id)"
    :key="team.id + networkTeam.id"
    :class="{ odd2: networkTeam.id % 2 !== 0 }"
>
```